# jQuery adding info when click current element

Tags: javascript

Lost my last account so I must create new but again Hi for all.

I have list of 6 divs, one like this:

```
<figure id="trener_1">
          <img class="img-responsive center" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/ex_wybierz_trenera1.jpg" alt="">
          <figcaption>
            <h4>Kasia Kowalska</h4>
          </figcaption>
          <a><div class="click_to text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <p>Kliknij aby wybrać trenera</p>
          </div></a>
        </figure>
        <section class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 xs-p-top">
            <div class="choose_info trener_1" style="display:none;">
              <img class="pull-left" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/check_trener.png" alt="">
              <p class="pull-left small-m-left xs-m-top text-bold">Wybrano trenera</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a href="szczegoly-trenera" target="_blank"><h3 class="btn-custom_bg pull-right">Zobacz profil trenera</h3></a>
          </div>
        </section>
```

And when clicking on figure with specific id, the element with the same class show. Now I have six elements like this (trener_2, trener_3 etc..) and I want when I choose one --> info shows. But when I click another ex. trener_2 info with class trener_2 shows but from trener_1 disappear.

My js:

```
$(function() {
            $('figure').click(function() {
                $("." + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn('slow').siblings().hide();
            });
        });
```

Sorry for my bad English, any suggest will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide all the `choose_info` elements except the current one so

```js
$(function() {
  $('figure').click(function() {
    var $t = $("." + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn('slow');
    $t.siblings().hide();
    $('.choose_info').not($t).hide().siblings().show()
  });
});
```

```css
.choose_info {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="trener_1">
  <img class="img-responsive center" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/ex_wybierz_trenera1.jpg" alt="">
  <figcaption>
    <h4>Kasia Kowalska</h4>
  </figcaption>
  <a>
    <div class="click_to text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      <p>Kliknij aby wybrać trenera</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</figure>
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 xs-p-top">
    <div class="choose_info trener_1" style="display:none;">
      <img class="pull-left" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/check_trener.png" alt="">
      <p class="pull-left small-m-left xs-m-top text-bold">Wybrano trenera</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="szczegoly-trenera" target="_blank"><h3 class="btn-custom_bg pull-right">Zobacz profil trenera</h3></a>
  </div>
</section>

<figure id="trener_2">
  <img class="img-responsive center" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/ex_wybierz_trenera1.jpg" alt="">
  <figcaption>
    <h4>Kasia Kowalska</h4>
  </figcaption>
  <a>
    <div class="click_to text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      <p>Kliknij aby wybrać trenera</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</figure>
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 xs-p-top">
    <div class="choose_info trener_2" style="display:none;">
      <img class="pull-left" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/check_trener.png" alt="">
      <p class="pull-left small-m-left xs-m-top text-bold">Wybrano trenera</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="szczegoly-trenera" target="_blank"><h3 class="btn-custom_bg pull-right">Zobacz profil trenera</h3></a>
  </div>
</section>

<figure id="trener_3">
  <img class="img-responsive center" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/ex_wybierz_trenera1.jpg" alt="">
  <figcaption>
    <h4>Kasia Kowalska</h4>
  </figcaption>
  <a>
    <div class="click_to text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      <p>Kliknij aby wybrać trenera</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</figure>
<section class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 xs-p-top">
    <div class="choose_info trener_3" style="display:none;">
      <img class="pull-left" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/check_trener.png" alt="">
      <p class="pull-left small-m-left xs-m-top text-bold">Wybrano trenera</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="szczegoly-trenera" target="_blank"><h3 class="btn-custom_bg pull-right">Zobacz profil trenera</h3></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Why not assign the class `trener_3` to the `div.row` element?

Comment: Figure have parents elements with grid but I only copy small peace of code.
Works perfect now! Thank you